# Structure value is not updating in main source file

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr

part of my project some of source files are 
`button_key.h, button_key.h, lcd.h, mani.c` etc.

Used a structre  in button_key.H and declared as

```
struct menu {
             uint8_t Hour;
             uint8_t Minute;
             uint8_t Second;
            };
```

In `main.c` source file

```
#include "lcd.h"
#include "delay.h"
#include "button_key.h"

  struct menu s1= {0}; 
  struct menu *ptr; 

int main(void)
{   int a;

    ptr = &s1;

//some code//
menu_key_display (s1,menu_display);
LCD_DisplayNumber(10,(*ptr).Hour,2); // here not updating the structure value as per the code in button_key.c  only show zero (0)
  while(1);

  // tried also LCD_DisplayNumber(10,s1.Hour,2); also seems same reult.

}
```

And the structre is used in `button_key.c` file like  (only the part of the code)

```
 void menu_key_display(struct menu s1,const char *menu_display[])
 {   //some cdoe here
       case 1: // set time
             { 
             LCD_Clear();
             LCD_GoToLine(0);
             LCD_DisplayString(menu_display[5]);
             LCD_GoToLine(1);
             LCD_DisplayString("  HH:MM:SS:PM/AM");
             UP_Down_Keyvalue(s1,2,4);            
              break;

             // some code 
 }
```

The above source code made changes , the values to the menu structure members. But that changes not reflect in main.c whats the wrong with me.

Comment: You need to pass `ptr` to the function.

Comment: arguments in `c` are pass by value. When you pass `.Hour` into `LCD_DisplayNumber`, a local copy of it is made. Any changes made to that local copy are lost when the function returns. If you want `s1.Hour` to retain its value when the function returns, you have to pass a pointer of it to `LCD_DisplayNumber` and dereference it in the function.

Comment: Pass as __struct menu*__ and use s1-> instead of s1.

Comment: @Yunnosch Ahh, right you are,, I honed in on the comment. Still not sure why `menu_key_display` is (was) repeated.

Comment: @yano I think OP only describes that the non-update is visible in the line starting with `LCD_DisplayNumber(...`, the cause is elsewhere.

Comment: @yano Double quote I guess is caused by jittery finger with ctrl-V. I double checked 100% identity before deleting.

Comment: @Yunnosch Heh yeah I just checked right before I saw you edited it. They were identical. I guess now OP is expecting `menu_key_display` to make lasting changes on `s1` via `Up_Down_Keyvalue`. The logic of what I said is right even though I was looking at the wrong function.

Comment: @Yano the logic is right, but trying to act on your comment will make sure that the error is not found because the cause is elsewhere. You can tell that OP is already focusing on the symptom instead of the cause, by the comments he added to the code.

Comment: @Yunnosch Very true, but it's a comment, not an answer, and it's too late to edit now. If the OP only has enough gumption to fix the problem by reading through the 2nd comment, then I don't have a whole lot of sympathy. Somebody should write an answer I suppose.

Comment: @yano You are somewhat right, but keep in mind that questions at StackOverflow are rarely asked by seasoned programmers (Everybody out there, I said "rarely", not "never", there are some great questions asked by people I bow to.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling an answer from comments:

The lack of updating is only **visible** in the lines you commented in your code, i.e. they are only the symptom.

The **cause** of the problem is one line earlier:

```
menu_key_display (s1,menu_display);
//                ^
```

In order to get the changes inside the function visible outside,
you need to use "call by reference", which in C means "via a pointer".

So, change the offending line to:

```
menu_key_display (ptr,menu_display);
```

That of course has to be matched by changes to lines of the called function:

```
void menu_key_display(struct menu *s1Ptr, const char *menu_display[])
// ...
UP_Down_Keyvalue(s1Ptr,2,4); // assuming this to be supposed to have the missing effect
//                ^
```

The last use of the pointer (in contrast to "call by value" struct copy) needs to be reflected in the `UP_DownKeyvalue(...)` function, too, in a similar way.
However, if it is a macro (which I think I implicitly assumed in the previous version of my answer), then `UP_Down_Keyvalue(*s1Ptr,2,4);` could be used without change to the macro definition.

Note, when working with pointer you might want to add a check to the function, to make sure that the pointer is not NULL. Call it paranoia, but paranoia is a healthy state of mind for a programmer (at least an embedded programmer).

Comment: There's not enough in the OP to know, but I'd have to assume `Up_Down_Keyvalue` should be called with a pointer also. Otherwise, in the code shown, `menu_key_display` won't edit the original `s1` and we're back to the same problem.

Comment: Good point, thank you. I fixed what is of course the point of the answer.